# How to see all local commits which are not pushed to the remote branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using the following commands to see all the local commits which are not pushed to remote branch but I am not getting all those local commits.

```
 git log  
 git log origin/master..master
```

I want to see at-least 10 local commits(only local).

Answer (score 188, accepted):

This will show you all not pushed commits from all branches

```
git log --branches --not --remotes
```

and this will show you all your local commits of branch `main`

```
git log origin/main..main
```

Comment: I get the first part, but what does "this must show you all your local commits" mean?

Comment: The first command not working for me - I have new branch that not pushed and the branch not showed

Comment: @NamGVU the command only shows commits not pushed, so new branches without commits are not listed.