# Show all commits without upstream branch

Tags: git, commit, git-branch

I want to show all my local commits on my branch even when I don't have an upstream branch.
If I have an upstream in place I usually use:

`$ git log @{u}..$(git branch --show-current)`

But this does not work if there is no upstream branch

I've also tried this answer from [Aleksander Monk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30601779/15337673):

`$ git log --branches --not --remotes`

Which is close to what I want but this shows me all the local commits on all branches. I'd want to filter this to show my commits only for current branch.

Is there a way to pipe this or is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short version : try

```
git log HEAD --not --remotes
```

---

More details :

The trick here is that without an upstream set, it's hard to know when to stop.  The usual version—for which you don't need `$(git branch --show-current)`—is to use `@{u}..` or `@{u}..HEAD` (whichever you prefer), which means *start from `HEAD`, i.e., the current commit* and *stop when reaching any commit reachable from the upstream*.  But that uses "the upstream".

The trick *there*—how to "know when to stop"—is to recast your formulation, just as you did:

> I've also tried this answer from Aleksander Monk:
>
> `$ git log --branches --not --remotes`
>
> Which is close to what I want but this shows me all the local commits
> on all branches. I'd want to filter this to show my commits only for
> current branch.

The problem with *this* version is that its positive reference is `--branches`, which means *all branch names*.  Its negative reference is `--remotes` (all remote-tracking names) and that's what you want; but you want `HEAD` as the *positive* reference.  So just swap in `HEAD` for `--branches`:

```
git log HEAD --not --remotes
```

and you're set.

(Note that when using `@{u}..` you can completely omit HEAD as it's implied by the two dots, but for this particular command, you can't *omit* `HEAD` at all.  You can, however, use the one-character short name `@` to mean `HEAD`, if you prefer.)

Comment: @LeGEC: I thought I was keeping this one short, by not expanding on positive and negative references 

Comment: aw man... I'm kicking myself for not thinking of this... Great answer and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the default behavior of `git log` (without any flags) on your branch.